# Symfony Doctrine entity relations returns null data on saving

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I've got problem with relations ManyToOne.
I have 2 entities:

```
namespace MyApp\PanelBundle\Entity;
use MyApp\PanelBundle\Entity\SupportMessagesThreads;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * SupportMessages
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="support_messages")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="MyApp\PanelBundle\Repository\SupportMessagesRepository")
 */
class SupportMessages
{
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="thread_id", type="integer")
     */
    private $thread_id;

    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="sender", type="integer")
     */
    private $sender;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="content", type="text")
     */
    private $content;

    /**
     * @var bool
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="is_read_sender", type="boolean")
     */
    private $is_read_sender;

    /**
     * @var bool
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="is_read_recipient", type="boolean")
     */
    private $is_read_recipient;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="created", type="datetime")
     */
    private $created;

     /**
      * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="SupportMessagesThreads", inversedBy="messages")
      * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="thread_id", referencedColumnName="id")
      */
     private $thread;

    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return int
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }


    /**
     * Set threadId
     *
     * @param integer $threadId
     *
     * @return SupportMessages
     */
    public function setThreadId($thread_id)
    {
        $this->thread_id = $thread_id;

        return $this;
    }


    /**
     * Get threadId
     *
     * @return int
     */
    public function getThreadId()
    {
        return $this->thread_id;
    }

    /**
     * Set sender
     *
     * @param integer $sender
     *
     * @return SupportMessages
     */
    public function setSender($sender)
    {
        $this->sender = $sender;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get sender
     *
     * @return int
     */
    public function getSender()
    {
        return $this->sender;
    }

    /**
     * Set content
     *
     * @param string $content
     *
     * @return SupportMessages
     */
    public function setContent($content)
    {
        $this->content = $content;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get content
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getContent()
    {
        return $this->content;
    }

    /**
     * Set isReadSender
     *
     * @param boolean $isReadSender
     *
     * @return SupportMessages
     */
    public function setIsReadSender($isReadSender)
    {
        $this->is_read_sender = $isReadSender;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get isReadSender
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function getIsReadSender()
    {
        return $this->is_read_sender;
    }

    /**
     * Set isReadRecipient
     *
     * @param boolean $isReadRecipient
     *
     * @return SupportMessages
     */
    public function setIsReadRecipient($isReadRecipient)
    {
        $this->is_read_recipient = $isReadRecipient;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get isReadRecipient
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function getIsReadRecipient()
    {
        return $this->is_read_recipient;
    }

    /**
     * Set created
     *
     * @param \DateTime $created
     *
     * @return SupportMessages
     */
    public function setCreated($created)
    {
        $this->created = $created;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get created
     *
     * @return \DateTime
     */
    public function getCreated()
    {
        return $this->created;
    }
    }
```

AND

```
<?php

namespace MyApp\PanelBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use MyApp\PanelBundle\Entity\SupportMessages;
/**
 * SupportMessagesThreads
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="support_messages_threads")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="MyApp\PanelBundle\Repository\SupportMessagesThreadsRepository")
 */
class SupportMessagesThreads
{
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="user_id", type="integer")
     */
    private $user_id;

    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="recipient", type="integer")
     */
    private $recipient;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="title", type="string")
     */
    private $title;

    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="status", type="integer")
     */
    private $status;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="created", type="datetime")
     */
    private $created;

     /**
      * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="SupportMessages", mappedBy="thread")
      */
    protected $messages;


    public function __construct()
    {
         $this->messages = new ArrayCollection();
    }
    /**
    * Get id
    *
    * @return int
    */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    function getMessages() {
         return $this->messages;
    }

    function setMessages($messages) {
         $this->messages = $messages;
    }

    /**
     * Set userId
     *
     * @param integer $userId
     *
     * @return SupportMessagesThreads
     */
    public function setUserId($userId)
    {
        $this->user_id = $userId;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get userId
     *
     * @return int
     */
    public function getUserId()
    {
        return $this->user_id;
    }

    /**
     * Set recipient
     *
     * @param integer $recipient
     *
     * @return SupportMessagesThreads
     */
    public function setRecipient($recipient)
    {
        $this->recipient = $recipient;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get recipient
     *
     * @return int
     */
    public function getRecipient()
    {
        return $this->recipient;
    }

    /**
     * Set title
     *
     * @param string $title
     *
     * @return SupportMessagesThreads
     */
    public function setTitle($title)
    {
        $this->title = $title;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get title
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getTitle()
    {
        return $this->title;
    }

    /**
     * Set status
     *
     * @param integer $status
     *
     * @return SupportMessagesThreads
     */
    public function setStatus($status)
    {
        $this->status = $status;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get status
     *
     * @return int
     */
    public function getStatus()
    {
        return $this->status;
    }

    /**
     * Set created
     *
     * @param \DateTime $created
     *
     * @return SupportMessagesThreads
     */
    public function setCreated($created)
    {
        $this->created = $created;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get created
     *
     * @return \DateTime
     */
    public function getCreated()
    {
        return $this->created;
    }
    }
```

In My Controller i have This code:

```
        $supportMessageThread = new SupportMessagesThreads();
        $supportMessageThread
                ->setUserId($this->getUser()->getId())
                ->setStatus(0)
                ->setTitle($formData->getTitle())
                ->setRecipient($formData->getRecipient())
                ->setCreated(new \DateTime());

        $supportMessage = new SupportMessages($formData);
        $supportMessage
                ->setThreadId($supportMessageThread)
                ->setCreated(new \DateTime())
                ->setIsReadSender(1)
                ->setIsReadRecipient(0)
                ->setSender($this->getUser()->getId())
                ->setContent($formData->message);

        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $em->persist($supportMessageThread);
        $em->persist($supportMessage);
        $em->flush();
```

My field called in @ORM\JoinColum name returns null every time. When i change "thread_id" to other fields ex. "sender" then "sender" field is null. What i can do to set id of SupportMessageThread entity to thread_id.

Printing data works fine. When i put test records to base manually and the next im get it by doctrine - everything is ok. The problem only occurs when save.

Please Help Me :((

Answer (score 0):

Probably you want to use [Cascade operations](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/working-with-associations.html#transitive-persistence-cascade-operations)

And your mapping looks a bit weird. Note that you declare the argument as integer

```
/**
 * Set threadId
 *
 * @param integer $threadId
 *
 * @return SupportMessages
 */
public function setThreadId($thread_id)
{
    $this->thread_id = $thread_id;

    return $this;
}
```

But SupportMessagesThreads is passed:

```
->setThreadId($supportMessageThread)
```

You should use objects instead scalars like

```
/**
 * Set thread
 *
 * @param SupportMessagesThreads $thread
 *
 * @return SupportMessages
 */
public function setThread(SupportMessagesThreads $thread)
{
    $this->thread = $thread;

    return $this;
}
```

and remove $thread_id field from SupportMessagesThreads

Answer (score 0):

In my case i had incorrect definitions of `inversed` and `mapped by`.
In both cases it was the same field `todo`.

That's the same case in the question above.

After changes it's

```
    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity=MyTodoElement::class, mappedBy="myTodo")
     */
    private $myTodoElement;
```

```
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity=MyTodo::class, inversedBy="myTodoElement")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
     */
    private $myTodo;
```